# Displaying HTML data into Textview creating issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

Hello I am trying to display HTML data in a textview. HTML data is a description of some content which includes paragraph change as well with a tag  in HTML.At first I was using HTML.fromhtml, but when I run my app there were no lines separator as you know  HTML.fromhtml removes all the HTML tags. Then I simply replaced all the  to /n. And it worked fine. But there may be a changes that some other tags will be displaced in future in my textview as I didn't used HTML.fromhtml. How to fix this issue? What to do?

This is the HTML Data

```
Vanaf nu kan je hier - tegelijkertijd met Italië en dus zonder gevaar op 
spoilers - het derde, bloedstollende seizoen van Gomorra bekijken. Dit is 
uniek in de Benelux!\r\n<br><br>\r\nZes weken lang komen er elke zaterdag 
twee nieuwe afleveringen online.\r\nNa aankoop van dit derde seizoen krijg 
je toegang tot de beschikbare afleveringen en worden nieuwe afleveringen 
automatisch toegevoegd aan je account.\r\n <br><br>\r\nHoud dus alvast deze 
zaterdagen vrij, want maffia was nooit eerder zo verslavend.\r\n <br>
<br>\r\n18\/11\/2017 – aflevering 1 en 2<br> 25\/11\/2017 – aflevering 3 en 
4<br>02\/12\/2017 – aflevering 5 en 6<br>09\/12\/2017 – aflevering 7 en 
8<br>16\/12\/2017 – aflevering 9 en 10<br>23\/12\/2017 – aflevering 11 en 
12<br>\r\n <br>\r\nSeizoen 1 en 2 nog niet gezien? Geniet tot 30 november 
van een verlaagde prijs op beide seizoenen (slechts €9.99).<br>\r\nPrego!",
```

And this method I am using to setText in my textview.

```
 public static Spanned getTextViewTextFromApi(String input) {
    Spanned result;
    String text;
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    text = "" + (input.replace("\\r\\n", newline).replace("\\n", newline));
    result = Html.fromHtml(text);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Spanned spanned;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        spanned = Html.fromHtml(mSampletext, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
    } else {

        spanned = Html.fromHtml(mSampletext);
    }
    System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Log.e("etagescaped", spanned+"") ;
    text.setText(spanned);


Answer: Vanaf nu kan je hier - tegelijkertijd met Italië en dus zonder gevaar op spoilers - het derde, bloedstollende seizoen van Gomorra bekijken. Dit is uniek in de Benelux! 

                                                            Zes weken lang komen er elke zaterdag twee nieuwe afleveringen online. Na aankoop van dit derde seizoen krijg je toegang tot de beschikbare afleveringen en worden nieuwe afleveringen automatisch toegevoegd aan je account. 

                                                            Houd dus alvast deze zaterdagen vrij, want maffia was nooit eerder zo verslavend. 

                                                            18/11/2017 – aflevering 1 en 2
                                                            25/11/2017 – aflevering 3 en 4
                                                            02/12/2017 – aflevering 5 en 6
                                                            09/12/2017 – aflevering 7 en 8
                                                            16/12/2017 – aflevering 9 en 10
                                                            23/12/2017 – aflevering 11 en 12

                                                            Seizoen 1 en 2 nog niet gezien? Geniet tot 30 november van een verlaagde prijs op beide seizoenen (slechts €9.99).
                                                            Prego!",
```

[screenshot of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSUDz.jpg)

Comment: In Logcat its showing perfectly.. But in device again showing in one paragraph.

Comment: Check the edited code and screenshot for the textview

Answer (score 0):

android textiview not fully supported HTML all tags view. you can use this [LIBRARY](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview). This library support all type of HTML tags which will set into android textview.

Supported HTML tags are :

```
<p>
<div> handled exactly like <p>
<br>
<b>
<i>
<strong> (bug on some Android versions: generates italic)
<em> (bug on some Android versions: generates bold)
<u>
<tt>
<dfn>
<sub>
<sup>
<blockquote>
<cite>
<big>
<small>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>
<a href="...">
<img src="...">

Extended support by HtmlTextView    
<ul>
<ol>
<li>
<code>
<center>
<strike>
```

Hope it will help you.